# Conditional $sum in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My collection in mongodb is similar to the following table in SQL:

Sentiments(Company,Sentiment)

Now, I need to execute a query like this:

```
SELECT
  Company, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Sentiment >0 THEN Sentiment ELSE 0 END) AS SumPosSenti, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Sentiment <0 THEN Sentiment ELSE 0 END) AS SumNegSenti
FROM Sentiments
GROUP BY Company
```

What should I do to write this query in Mongo? I am stuck at the following query:

```
db.Sentiments.aggregate(
{ $project: {_id:0, Company:1, Sentiment: 1} },
{ $group: {_id: "$Company", SumPosSenti: {$sum: ? }, SumNegSenti: {$sum: ? } } }
);
```

Comment: You might be able to use a `$cond` in the sum: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#conditional-expressions but it sounds like a butchery of speed and scalable querying, I can imagine this query was slow in SQL and will be slow here on a medium result set

Comment: @Sammaye I am trying to replace '?' with {$cond: { Sentiment: { $gte: 0} } } . But that looks like a wrong syntax.. I'm not getting any output.

Comment: $cond works like an if statement exactly like a case, so the first expression would be: `Sentiment >0` and then `Sentiment` and then `0` for the first $cond in the first $sum

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As Sammaye suggested, you need to use the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond) aggregation projection operator to do this:

```js
db.Sentiments.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        Company: 1,
        PosSentiment: {$cond: [{$gt: ['$Sentiment', 0]}, '$Sentiment', 0]},
        NegSentiment: {$cond: [{$lt: ['$Sentiment', 0]}, '$Sentiment', 0]}
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$Company",
        SumPosSentiment: {$sum: '$PosSentiment'},
        SumNegSentiment: {$sum: '$NegSentiment'}
    }});
```

Answer (score 63):

Starting from version 3.4, we can use the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator which allows logical condition processing in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. Of course we still need to use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum) accumulator to return the sum.

```
db.Sentiments.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$Company",  
            "SumPosSenti": { 
                "$sum": { 
                    "$switch": { 
                        "branches": [ 
                            { 
                                "case": { "$gt": [ "$Sentiment", 0 ] }, 
                                "then": "$Sentiment"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "default": 0 
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "SumNegSenti": {
                "$sum": { 
                    "$switch": { 
                        "branches": [ 
                            { 
                                "case": { "$lt": [ "$Sentiment", 0 ] }, 
                                "then": "$Sentiment"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "default": 0 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

---

If you have not yet migrated your `mongod` to 3.4 or newer, then note that  the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) stage in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14102916/) is redundant because the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond) operator returns a numeric value which means that you can [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents and apply [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to the `$cond` expression.

This will improve the performance in your application especially for large collection.

```
db.Sentiments.aggregate(
    [
        { '$group': {
            '_id': '$Company',
            'PosSentiment': { 
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': [
                        { '$gt': ['$Sentiment', 0]}, 
                        '$Sentiment', 
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'NegSentiment': { 
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': [
                        { '$lt': ['$Sentiment', 0]}, 
                        '$Sentiment', 
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

---

Consider a collection Sentiments with the following documents:

```
{ "Company": "a", "Sentiment" : 2 }
{ "Company": "a", "Sentiment" : 3 }
{ "Company": "a", "Sentiment" : -1 }
{ "Company": "a", "Sentiment" : -5 }
```

The aggregation query produces:

```
{ "_id" : "a", "SumPosSenti" : 5, "SumNegSenti" : -6 }
```

Comment: FYI, this also works for use cases where you want to check a boolean or string instead of a number.

Use `$eq` instead for a direct match, and make sure you set your `then` value to the number you want to count by (ex. `then: 1`)

Answer (score 10):

Explaining the snippets above, that uses the array syntax:

```
PosSentiment: {$cond: [{$gt: ['$Sentiment', 0]}, '$Sentiment', 0]}
```

is equal to:

```
PosSentiment: {$cond: { if: {$gt: ['$Sentiment', 0]}, then: '$Sentiment', else: 0} }
```

The array syntax summarizes the long syntax to just `{ $cond: [if, then, else] }`