# MongoDB $group and explicit group formation with computed column

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, calculated-columns

Consider this code in SQL that forms groups based on a range of salary:

`;With TableWithComputedColumn as 
(

 select

computedcolumn =

 Case

 when Salary<30000 then 'Under 30K' 

 when Salary>30000 and Salary<60000 then '30K-60K'

else 'Above 60K' 

end 
from Tbl_UserMaster

)

select computedcolumn, COUNT(*)

from TableWithComputedColumn
group by computedcolumn`

I want to do this in Mongo.. My guess is that the CTE part will require me to first output `{computed column}` to a temporary collection and then do a `$group` on that collection. Another way (and the one I prefer) could be to use `$project` to project `{computed column}` as the first stream in the 
aggregation pipeline and then perform `$group`.

`db.UM.aggregate(
{$project: { "computed_column": { //something with $cond}} },

{$group: {_id: {Salary_Slab:"$computed_column"}, count: {$sum:1}}}

);`

Please also go through a similar question I had asked before:

[Conditional $sum in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102596/conditional-sum-in-mongodb)

It basically gives me a pivoted output. In this situation, I need unpivoted output. To compare the two, the answer to the other question will create three columns:{Under 30K, 30K-60K, Above 60K} with a single row of counts, whereas I need three rows for Under 30K, 30K-60K, and Above 60K in one column and their respective counts in the second column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  In this case you need to nest `$cond` operators like this:

```js
db.UM.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        computed_column: {$cond: [{$gt: ['$Salary', 30000]},
            {$cond: [{$gt: ['$Salary', 60000]}, 'Above 60K', '30K-60K']},
            'Under 30K']}
    }},
    { $group: {_id: {Salary_Slab: '$computed_column'}, count: {$sum: 1}}})
```

results:

```js
[ { _id: { Salary_Slab: 'Above 60K' }, count: 3 },
  { _id: { Salary_Slab: '30K-60K' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { Salary_Slab: 'Under 30K' }, count: 2 } ]
```

Comment: Oh cool! It didn't occur to me that $cond could be nested. Thanks a lot!