# Mongo aggregation filter

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have several map-reduce jobs that run on a scheduler and aggregate some counts for us. We'd like to switch these over to real time aggregate calls. The problem is, the map-reduce in all it's infinite flexibility is tallying 4 different counts for the collection it runs against. Things like:

```
var result =
    {
        MessageId: this.MessageId,
        Date: this.Created,
        Queued : (this.Status == 0 ? 1 : 0),
        Sent : (this.Status == 1 ? 1 : 0),
        Failed : (this.Status == 2 ? 1 : 0),
        Total : 1,
        Unsubscribes: 0
    };
```

If I were in SQL I don't think I could pull this off with a single GROUP BY/SUM, because I need a different filter for each SUM. Is it possible in mongo, or do I need to run 4 separate $group statements with different $match clauses?

Comment: You can use `$cond` in a `$project` to do this sort of thing, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14102916/1259510).

Comment: cool, thanks. is there some way I can mark my answer as a duplicate or just delete it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional $sum in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102596/conditional-sum-in-mongodb)

Comment: You can click 'close' to vote to close your question as a duplicate like I just did.