# Count where value does not match array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following `offers` collection

Here `readBy` contains the `_id` of the users...
Now I want to count the number of unRead offers for the `userId = "5add82620d7f5b38240c63d4"`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeaab5ed6a9c97d0209260a"),
    "expiresIn" : ISODate("2018-05-30T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "Trip ",
    "readBy" : [ 
        ObjectId("5add82620d7f5b38240c63d4"),
        ObjectId("5add82620d7f5b38240c63c6")
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeaab7dd6a9c97d0209260b"),
    "expiresIn" : ISODate("2018-05-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "Trip",
    "readBy" : [ObjectId("5add82620d7f5b38240c63d4")],
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeae233d6a9c97d02092622"),
    "expiresIn" : ISODate("2018-05-25T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "two way off",
    "readBy" : [],
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeae49643f10d284726069c"),
    "expiresIn" : ISODate("2018-05-25T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "two way off",
    "readBy" : [],
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeae49743f10d284726069d"),
    "expiresIn" : ISODate("2018-05-25T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "two way off",
    "readBy" : []
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeae49743f10d284726069e"),
    "expiresIn" : ISODate("2018-05-25T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "two way off",
    "readBy" : []
}
```

so for the above collection my output should be

```
[{
  numberOfUnreadOffers: 4
}]
```

because four of the collection does not have `5add82620d7f5b38240c63d4` in `readBy` array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional $sum in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102596/conditional-sum-in-mongodb)

Comment: @Héctor with the exception of course that "aggregation" is actually the wrong approach for the most performant solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically use [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) and [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) here:

```
var userId= "5add82620d7f5b38240c63d4";

Model.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "numberOfUnreadOffers": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { 
            "$setIsSubset": [[mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)], "$readBy"]
          },
          "then": 0,
          "else": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Of course you also need to "cast" using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` from the "string" to a valid `ObjectId` value.

But really you get better performance from a simple [`count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#count_count) instead:

```
Model.count({ "readBy": { "$ne": userId } })
```

So you really should not use `.aggregate()` for this at all.

Comment: perfect Neil... where you do test with the queries? I mean there is site like jsFiddle to test mongodb query?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary Where do "I" test? Usually "nowhere" and this stuff just comes out of my head, which explains why there are usually syntax errors :) If a question correctly shows data and I actually need to think about it for a few moments, then I'll simply copy and paste to insert to a new collection and then run the queries that matter. Always have a MongoDB instance you can trash with rubbish collections and test things I guess. Better than any "fiddle".