# How to compare string feild value in aggregation mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-compass, nosql-aggregation

in the following image i am using *$project* aggregation. i need to compare whether **text** feild is equals to 'A' or not using *$cond*. If this boolean condition is true it should return 1 otherwise 0. but it is showing **Stage must be properly formatted.**

```
{
  'answers.Urban_City.text': 1,
  SEC_A: {$cond:['answers.SEC.text':['$eq','A'], 1,  0]}
}
```

[compass image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlkLe.png)

**Sample document**
i have multiple documents like this

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61dea2c1169cd059e2d1a06e"
  },
  "metaKey": {
    "projectId": 7,
    "sectionId": 5,
    "userId": 5,
    "simpleSurveyResponseCode": "58836213476714"
  },
  "answers": [
    {
      "Urban_City": {
        "text": "Karachi",
        "value": "72"
      }
    },
    {
      "SEC": {
        "text": "A",
        "value": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want something like this

```
db.Sentiments.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        Company: 1,
        PosSentiment: {$cond: [{$gt: ['$Sentiment', 0]}, '$Sentiment', 0]},
        NegSentiment: {$cond: [{$lt: ['$Sentiment', 0]}, '$Sentiment', 0]}
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$Company",
        SumPosSentiment: {$sum: '$PosSentiment'},
        SumNegSentiment: {$sum: '$NegSentiment'}
    }});
```

but at the place of **Sentiment** i have SEC which is embedded array contains two feilds(*String*) mentioned in sample document. where i have stuck in $project aggregation if this gets resolved $group would be easy for me.

Comment: Try `{$cond:[{$eq: ['$answers.SEC.text','A']}, 1,  0]}` Looks like you mixed aggregation operator [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) and query operator [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)

Comment: i used {$cond:[{$eq: ['$answers.SEC.text','A']}, 1,  0]}. but it always return false, nothing gets matched, result in 0 return in $cond. i dont know why.

Comment: Please provide same sample input documents.

Comment: i have provided sample document in my question

Comment: The sample data does not match at all to your aggregation pipeline. What is the desired result?

Comment: I want to find the documents of answers.SEC.text: A in project pipeline, These documents in found in $project stage, will get count in the next stage of $group(e.g. group by "answers.Urban_City.text:Karachi")

For further clearity you can refer to the following stackoverflow link. But please note in the place of Sentiment i  have answers.SEC.text; where SEC is embedded object which contains two feilds (text, value).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102596/conditional-sum-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         'answers.Urban_City.text': 1,
         SEC_A: {
            $map: {
               input: "$answers",
               in: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$$this.SEC.text', 'A'] }, 1, 0] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

If you provide a desired sample output, the change will be much higher to receive an appropriate answer.

Comment: Your answer showing error "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field".

Comment: I have edit my questioncan you please refer